# Setting timeout function to add a class for Jquery on hover function

Tags: jquery

When a user hovers on a div I add one class. After the hover is finished I remove the first class and add a different class. The problem is that I want to remove the second class after 1.5 seconds from adding it.

So far my code adds the classes, but does not execute function with timeout.

```
$('.portfolio-card').hover(function() { 
  $(this).addClass('hover') 
}, function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('hover');  
  $(this).addClass('hover-over', setTimeout(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('hover-over'); 
  }, 1500));
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `addClass()` and `setTimeout()` isn't quite right. They need to be called separately. You also need to retain the reference to `this` in the outer event handler scope, as within the `setTimeout()` handler it will refer to the `window`, not the element which raised the event.

As a side note, it's better practice to use CSS's `:hover` selector where possible over JS. Therefore you can amend your code to just use `mouseleave` instead of `hover()`. Try this:

```js
$('.portfolio-card').on('mouseleave', function() {
  var $el = $(this).addClass('hover-over');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $el.removeClass('hover-over');
  }, 1500);
})
```

```css
.portfolio-card:hover {
  color: red;
}

.hover-over {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-card">
  Hover me
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for such quick and clear answer! :)